# What is a good Python library for decision trees?

Tags: python, decision-tree

Unless I'm missing something, the usual suspects don't have this....

Comment: Consider the catch-22... we could give you a decision tree for choosing one but you'd have no way of evaluating it. :-)

Comment: Drop Python and use R (or Rpy).

Comment: @mbq: prepare to defend such a bold claim. Why drop Python and use R?

Comment: @Eli that is just a suggestion; it may be a simpler solution, so I mentioned it, but of course only Ash R can judge that.

Comment: Just to keep you from going insane implementing your own logic in Python, why not wrap C4.5 in a subprocess or use that through an Orange module or use the tree-building modules in Orange? http://www.ailab.si/orange/doc/reference/C45Learner.htm

Comment: @mbq: Ash's last name is R, so he's already using it. :)

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: I don't think so; in R it is so simple that there is no need to ask.

Comment: @mbq: …so he's already using it (as a last name, in the Ash R persona)… I just reply because your answer seems to be serious. Anyway, it's not your fault, just my unfunny sense of humour.

Comment: I know; probably I should have used a ';-)'. Nevertheless its true.

Comment: Thanks folks - in the end I found using weka and jython was the best solution.

Comment: There is a related question on Stats Stackexchange site: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/boosted-decision-trees-in-python

Answer (score 4):

There is a [DecisionTreeLearner class](http://aima-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/learning.py) as part of the [Python library](http://code.google.com/p/aima-python/) for Russell & Norvig's "Artificial  Intelligence: A Modern Approach" textbook.

Comment: Do they include "ID3" trees as well?

Answer (score 4):

There is also Scikit Learn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification
Haven't tried it though (but I'm about to).

Answer (score 0):

I was finding python decision tree library, too.
there are many open source decision tree libraries on the internate, and I found out [DecisionTree](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/distDT/DecisionTree-1.7.html) from Kak, who is a professor in Purdue, is the most useful one.

just want to update the information, so people who are looking for decision tree library can save some effort.

Unfortunately, the library does not implement numeric feature values and treats each number as a different class.